# Unreadable lines of Milnor's book

Tags: differential-topology, cobordism

What are the (exact sentence of) Unreadable lines of the following images of Milnor's *Lecture on h-cobordism theorem*? (pages number: 28, 30, 15 respectively)
[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Why do you think there must be lines missing, and where?

Comment: It is unreadable and not missing. the question is vague?

Comment: @C.F.G: Do you mean the half lines where you have cropped the pictures?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, End of each picture.

Comment: @NickD, "... with respect to the Morse function f," I know, but does f has any indices or something else?

Comment: Sounds like you need to get your hands on a better copy.

Comment: @C.F.G: Adding a tag for a particular book is discouraged, see e.g. [Is it OK to create a tag about exercises from one particular book?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29359/42969). –  This is currently [discussed in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51550183#51550183), you are welcome to chime in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**p. 28** "with respect to the Morse function $f$, is well-defined (i.e., independent of choice of $f$ and $p$)."

**p. 30**  "(2) $(\vec{x},\vec{y})$ lies on the orthogonal trajectory which passes through the point $(u\cosh\theta,v\sinh \theta)$."

**p. 15** "$N_1$ of $f_1$, $N_1\subset N$, so that any function in $N_1$ is still good on $C_1$. This completes the first stage."

Comment: Thanks. but for p. 28, I need words before "independent of choice". Thanks also for noticing hidden text "$f$ and $p$". I never see this.

Comment: @C.F.G I edited my answer. Let me know if you need further help.